# AWS RDS Optimized Memory vs Burstable Instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am currently using Memory optimized DB class in AWS (8 CPUs) because some push notifications in our app cause the CPU utilization to skyrocket, but 99% of the time CPU utilization is at about 10% so 8 CPUs aren't really needed most of the time.

Would I be able to deploy less CPUs on a Burstable Instance and have CPUs adjusted when there are those heavy traffic push notifications?

How do Burstable Instances work?

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
AWS type today? Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
AND very helpful OS information, includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Some educational material from AWS at this URL - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances.html   Should be helpful.

Comment: High CPU means you have a query that needs a better index and/or better formulation.  Find that query and let's discuss it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wouldn't choose a burstable instance for any production traffic.

The burstable instance accumulates a number of "performance credits" per hour. These credits can be consumed when traffic increases and you needs a significant amount of resources. When the credits are spent, the instance still runs, but has only "baseline performance" which is, frankly, insufficient to handle production traffic.

I've seen many users try to economize by using the T family of instance types. They are usually quite disappointed, because they underestimate their need for resources. They end up consuming their burst credits too quickly, and then operate at the baseline performance level too often.

I'd use a burstable instance only for CI testing servers, or development. These instances typically run idle most of the time, and accumulate a good level of performance credits. They use these credits for brief periods, and then return to an idle level of activity.

Note: There is also the "Unlimited" option, which T3 instances use by default. This changes the nature of the burst performance. You can get greater CPU performance over prolonged periods, but you end up paying more for it. To understand the details, read https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-credits-baseline-concepts.html carefully.

You can also look into Aurora Serverless. This is supposed to auto-scale more replica instances in response to traffic increases, which should give you more CPU capacity. You only pay for the instances you use. That's the theory, but I can't speak from experience because I haven't used or tested Aurora Serverless. How well it works and how economical it is for you depends on your application's workload. All I can suggest is to give it a try.

Which instance type and options are best for you is greatly dependent on your specific application's traffic pattern. Does it have consistent load, or cyclical load (for example, high load during business hours but less at night)? Is it mostly CPU-bound, memory-bound, I/O-bound, or network-bound? You need to understand your application's resource needs before you can pick the best instance type.

Comment: It's not true that the instance will run only with "baseline performance". It will run with full performance but you will be charged extra accordingly. "Amazon RDS T4g and T3 DB instances run in Unlimited mode, which means that you will be charged if your average CPU utilization over a rolling 24-hour period exceeds the baseline of the instance. CPU Credits are charged at $0.09 per vCPU-Hour. The CPU Credit pricing is the same for all T4g and T3 instance sizes across all regions and is not covered by Reserved Instances."

Comment: @TommyN Thanks for the correction. I know I have seen cases where T-class instances have performance decline suddenly. Maybe that was based on an earlier generation. AWS behavior changes from year to year.

Answer (score 1):

I believe most RDBMS, particularly MySQL, can only be scaled "vertically", in the sense that you can't dynamically add/remove CPU resources to handle bursts of reads/writes.

Perhaps you can create a "notification/fanout" service which is more easily dynamically scaled up and down, using perhaps DynamoDB or AWS SNS. This way your primary database can avoid all of that traffic and in turn you can use a much less expensive EC2 instance for your RDS.

Comment: Sounds like you meant "can only be scaled *horizontally*", as adding CPUs is scaling vertically.